# What are the most important skill/knowldege sets for a network administrator to have to support VOIP?

Tags: networking, cisco, troubleshooting, voip, protocol-analyzer

As a network administrator (Cisco switches, work with WAN providers, protocol analysis) I have an "area of responsibility" for the customer's VOIP project.  The telecom group has primary responsibility for dial plans, voice mail and the monitoring tools that came with the Avaya system, but the traffic goes over the data network, so at some point I expect to be involved.

QoS has been implemented.  I have not yet received any formal training, and most of the training offerings I have seen have had more to do with VOIP administration than data network related issues.

Comment: Isn't this sort of clost to this post?: http://serverfault.com/questions/49891/how-should-i-structure-a-voip-phone-system/49895#49895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the network knowledge, best thing to do is get familiar with the debugging and troubleshooting tools of the vendor's specific system.

Other than that, excellent Google skills... :)

Answer (score 1):

Network knowledge is great!... now try to **research about the actual traffic being passed through your network**.  Become familiar with the logical and physical topologies of your VoIP infrastructure.  Most training you find will definitely have to have QoS implementation and troubleshooting which should help you, not harm you.

- Good whitepaper about VoIP: [**http://www.iec.org/online/tutorials/int_tele/index.asp**](http://www.iec.org/online/tutorials/int_tele/index.asp)
- SIP Protocol information: [**http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/SIP**](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/SIP)
- If you want to go deep into the actual **traffic generated by VoIP**, you might want to start looking at actual packet dumps.  Here's a good resource (Search specifically for SIP and RTP):

  [**http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures**](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#head-6f6128a524888c86ee322aa7cbf0d7b7a8fdf353)

Also, ake close look at what people tend to ask about **VoIP**, specially in this great site: [**https://serverfault.com/search?q=VoIP**](https://serverfault.com/search?q=VoIP)